# Is there a Wizard/ Thief class

Tags: dnd-5e

Is there  an example of a wizard/ thief  character class?

Comment: What do you mean wizard/thief character class? A class for being both a magic user and thief? A multiclass example?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to rpg.se! If you haven't already, take the [tour] to get a feel of how things are done in this site. Regarding your question, it seems to be attracting downvotes because of the lack of research effort on your question. Here, we assume that askers have made efforts to research or at least google the question before asking. It also seems unclear what you are asking. Do you mean if a Wizard can multiclass into a _Rogue_? or do you mean gestalt Wizard/Rogue characters? Don't be discouraged by the negative votes, new users almost always have to get used to the site's format first.

Comment: Personally, what I find confusing is the question about literature. If there isn't one in the game... you want to know — what, exactly? Whether magic-using thieves exist in any literature ever could be what you mean, but that's not really a question that's on-topic for the site, so maybe you mean something different. Do you?

Comment: I am removing the reference to literature. We cannot handle a request for arbitrary wizardy/theify characters - there's a lot so we're just going to build up a list, and literary research is not our forte.

Comment: Does he just want a stealthy arcane user ???

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. The Arcane Trickster  seems to be a good approach. The side question about literature refers to in what book would I find a similar character. i.e a barbarian Fahrd (Swords and Deviltry), Ranger - Strider (LOTR) ...

Answer (score 9):

The Arcane Trickster is an archetype for Rogues that is designed to be a classic Wizard/Thief. They supplement their criminal skills with illusions and enchantments.

It is described in pages 97-98 in the Player's Handbook.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli I don't want to get into all the ways that you *could* do a Wizard/Thief - this question is teetering on the edge as is. The Arcane Trickster is explicitly intended to be the Wizard/Thief, so I'm going to leave my answer at that.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to make a Wizard/Thief within a single class in DND 5e.

One is the Arcane Trickster which is a Thief/Wizard, a subclass choice for the Rogue class.

Another option is any magic casting class with a Criminal, Charlatan, Street Urchin or Spy background. You can also create your own background which provides proficiency in Thieves tools, and either sleight of hand or deception skills.

A Warlock can also be built to be a type of Wizard/Thief, by choosing the appropriate invocations and spell choices.

The Bard class can also be looked at as a Wizard/Thief/Fighter/Cleric, which contains Wizard/Thief within and can be built to focus on those two areas.

And lastly, the least obvious Wizard/Thief would be a Monk focused on the way of the shadow.

Comment: Thanks Looking at the Arcane Trickster, that subclass seems to be a good fit. Using a warlock could be an intriguing option.